# HTML Google Maps Customized

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps

I am working on a website and I used to embed google maps the simpler way, although, I would like to know how is it possible to customize my google map like in this picture, I mean how can I make it full responsive, with no annoying arrows and no other options, only the map with this colors.

If anyone knows how to do it please provide some help, if there is any website with some simple samples, it would be great.

Notice that I know how to embed google maps on my website, I just don't know how to customize like this image (that's what I really wanted):

[image]

Comment: using gmap3, you can customize marker. http://gmap3.net/en/pages/19-demo/

Comment: Additionally have you completely read through the Google Maps API Documentation? Google are always VERY thorough with this stuff and your problem seems like a result of not reading that documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style google maps.

The following example turns all map features to gray, then colors arterial road geometry in blue, and hides business labels completely

```
  var styleArray = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -80 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.arterial",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffee" },
      { saturation: 50 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "poi.business",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];
```

Please refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1) for detailed info

Comment: Better write it as a comment instead of answer to avoid downvotes.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to post it as a comment.